# Use of case statement in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve a list from the database using this statement:

```
select 
  distinct c.value_1 
from 
  aprposcode a 
  INNER JOIN aprwagerule b on a.client = b.client 
  and a.wage_rule = b.wage_rule 
  and b.scale_from != 'AAA-00' 
  INNER JOIN aprvalues c on b.client = c.client 
  and b.scale_from = c.dim_value 
  and getdate () between c.date_from 
  and c.date_to 
where 
  a.post_code = $posc 
  and a.client = $client
```

The $ are parameters that will auto-populate. I then want the sql to retrieve the data only when a certain field is set to a value on EXCL, i have tried this sql but it does not work:

```
select 
  distinct c.value_1 
from 
  aprposcode a 
  INNER JOIN aprwagerule b on a.client = b.client 
  and a.wage_rule = b.wage_rule 
  and b.scale_from != 'AAA-00' 
  INNER JOIN aprvalues c on b.client = c.client 
  and b.scale_from = c.dim_value 
  and getdate () between c.date_from 
  and c.date_to 
where 
  a.post_code = $posc 
  and a.client = $client case when $lab != 'EXCL' then 1 else 0 end
```

Is the case statement correct or should it be placed elsewhere?

Comment: It belongs elsewhere, but without knowing what it should be affecting it's impossible to know where

Comment: Do you have to add a `=1` after the case-end? The CASE expression gives a value, while the WHERE wants a comparison

Comment: @HansKeﬆing But then you could just use `AND $lab != 'EXCL'`. It's not clean what the result of that case statement should be compared to.